# Proving $\sin(x^2)$ Continuous but Not Uniformly Continuous with non-standard Definition

Tags: general-topology, continuity, proof-writing, metric-spaces, solution-verification

> Show that the bounded function $f(x) = \sin(x^2)$ is continuous, but not uniformly continuous, on the interval $[0,\infty)$.

The problem should be solved using the following definitions:

**Definition of Continuous Function**
Let $X$ and $Y$ be metric spaces. We sat that a function $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is *continuous* if given any open set $V \subseteq Y$, its inverse image $f^{-1}(V)$ is an open subset of $X$.

**Definition of Uniformly Continuous Function**
Let $(X,d_x)$ and $(Y,d_y)$ be metric spaces. If $E \subseteq X$, then we say that a function $f: X\rightarrow Y$ is *uniformly continuous* on $E$ if for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that for all $x,y \in E$ we have $$d_x(x,y) < \delta \longrightarrow d_y(f(x),f(y)) < \epsilon$$

For the continuity part it is clear that $f^{-1}(a,b), (a,b) \subseteq (-1,1) = \{x:f(x) \in (a,b)\}$ which appears to be an open set however I doubt this is sufficient as a proof since it holds for any function $f$.

Not sure how to go about proving $f$ not uniformly continuous. Seems to be difficult to prove from the definition alone.

Comment: Prove the lemma: if $f$ is uniformly continuous  then $f$ has the following property: if $(x_n)$ and $y_n$ are sequences in the domain such that $d(x_n, y_n) \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$, then $d(f(x_n), f(y_n)) \to 0$ as well. Refute that property and you refute uniform continuity.

Comment: Henno has a good idea, but let me maybe state it this way: If you are uniformly continuous, your choice of epsilon does **not** depend on your choice of points. The idea is to now show that there are points where $\epsilon$ will depend on them.

Answer (score 1):

First, write down the Inverse Negtive Proposition of Uniformly Continuous. Then we now how to prove a function is not uniformly continuous.

Then, let $a_n=\sqrt{2n\pi+\dfrac{\pi}{2}}$ and $b_n=\sqrt{2n\pi-\dfrac{\pi}{2}}$. It is easy to prove that when $n\rightarrow +\infty$, $a_n-b_n\rightarrow 0$, but $f(a_n)-f(b_n)=2$. Therefore we proved $f$ is not a Uniformly Continuous Function.

For continuity, I think your proof missed some key points. It's better to prove the solution subset is open by solving equations. (here we need to consider 3 consitions)

Answer (score 0):

Let's prove Henno's claim, and then in the comments you can try and fill in the blanks for how to finish things.

**Henno claim:** If $(x_n), (y_n)$ are sequences with $d(x_n, y_n) \rightarrow 0$ and $f$ is uniformly continuous, then $d(f(x_n), f(y_n)) \rightarrow 0$.

The goal is to show if $(x_n), (y_n)$ are sequences with $d(x_n, y_n) \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$, then $d(f(x_n), f(y_n)) \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$. We want to show that for all $\epsilon >0$ there is an $N$ so that for all $n \geq N$ we have
$$ d(f(x_n), f(y_n)) < \epsilon.$$

By definition of uniform continuity, for all $\epsilon >0$ there is a $\delta >0$ so that
$$d(x,y) < \delta \implies d(f(x), f(y)) < \epsilon.$$

Let's fix arbitrary $\epsilon > 0$. Then uniform continuity tells us that there is some $\delta > 0$ so the above property holds. Since $d(x_n, y_n) \rightarrow 0$, there exists an $N$ so that for all $n \geq N$, $d(x_n, y_n) < \delta$. The definition of uniform continuity then says that $d(f(x_n), f(y_n)) < \epsilon$, as desired.

How would one use this to prove something is *not* uniformly continuous? Find two sequences which get arbitrarily close together but for which the function applied to them does not get arbitrarily close together. What sequences are a good choice here?

Comment: How would you ago about proving regular continuity?

Comment: Is $\sin(x)$ continuous? Is $x^2$ continuous?

Comment: Once you know that, apply https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/527855/real-analysis-continuity-of-a-composition-function