# Proof function with two variables is continuous $f(x,y) = 2xy/(x^2+y^2)$

Tags: limits

I have this function:

$f(x,y)= \frac{2xy}{x^2+y^2}$ if $(x,y)$ is not $(0,0)$.

Now I want to prove that this function is continuous. I have tried using the epsilon delta method, but I don't really know if it works with a two variables function. The $|f(x)-f(a)|$ seems to get very complicated, because of the $(x,y)-(a_1,a_2)$. How should I approach this proof?

Comment: You're defining your function in $\;\Bbb R^2\setminus\{(0,0)\}\;$ and here you have the ratio of two polynomials and the denominator polynomial doesn't vanish....thus the function is continuous as the ratio of two continuous functions.

Comment: try polar coordinates

Answer (score 2):

Your function is continuous as a composition of continuous functions on $\mathbb{R}^2 \backslash \{(0,0)\}$ as DonAntonio suggested.

[Real Analysis: Continuity of a Composition Function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/527855/real-analysis-continuity-of-a-composition-function)

$z(x,y) = \frac{x}{y}$,

$g(x,y) = 2xy$

$h(x,y) = x^2+y^2$

Then $f(x,y) = z(g(x,y),h(x,y))$

Comment: That's a great solution! Thanks